# developing asp.net mvc app, index table overlaps page border

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, border

I am developing my first web app after years of C# Windows Forms development in .NET.  I've been following the NerdDinner tutorial and making changes where needed to suit my programs needs.  I have some more things to add, but currently all the functionality is working.

I've kept my Index View as a table.  When it displays, the table is wider than the browser window (even when maximized) and I can use the scroll bar at the bottom to view the entire table.  However, there is a border around the browser window that the table overlaps, so the second half of my table is over the blue border rather than the white.  I haven't made any changes to the site.css yet.  I've tried to do some web searches for solutions, but they're too broad since I don't know which element needs to be changed.  Most of the stuff I'm coming across is to update the border on the table, not the page.

```
    /*----------------------------------------------------------
The base color for this template is #5c87b2. If you'd like
to use a different color start by replacing all instances of
#5c87b2 with your new color.
----------------------------------------------------------*/
body
{
    background-color: #5c87b2; 
    font-size: .75em;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969; 
    /* width: auto; */
}

a:link
{
    color: #034af3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited
{
    color: #505abc;
}
a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active
{
    color: #12eb87;
}

p, ul
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h2
{
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0;
}

/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* you can specify a greater or lesser percentage for the 
page width. Or, you can specify an exact pixel width. */
.page
{
    /* width: auto; */
    /* width: 90%; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

#header
{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
}

#header h1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px !important;
}

#main
{
    padding: 30px 30px 15px 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    _height: 1px; /* only IE6 applies CSS properties starting with an underscrore */
}

#footer
{
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .9em;
}

/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu
{
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li#greeting
{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li a
{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    color: #034af3;
}

ul#menu li a:hover
{
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:active
{
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li.selected a
{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

/* FORM LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset 
{
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset label 
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input[type="text"] 
{
    width: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

input[type="password"] 
{
    width: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

/* TABLE
----------------------------------------------------------*/

table 
{
  border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td 
{
  padding: 5px;   
  border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
}

table th
{
  padding: 6px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #e8eef4; 
  border: solid 1px #e8eef4;   
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.error
{
    color: Red;
}

#menucontainer
{
    margin-top:40px;
}

div#title
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}

#logindisplay
{
    font-size:1.1em;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    margin:10px;
    color:White;
}

#logindisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logindisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#logindisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.field-validation-error
{
    color: #ff0000;
}

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing any examples you could try this in the site.css file.

Locate the "body" class.

Change, or add, an attribute such as `width:800px` or `min-width:450px` or you may even be able to do `width:auto`.

These are generally the settings I use for my sites.

You may also need to play around with the #main class.

Comment: I have played around with the body, .page, and main classes with no luck.  I suppose the easiest thing to do is just make the background all white, but I don't think that looks good at all.

Comment: No you're right, it doesn't.  I think the background isn't resizing because somewhere, the width is being set.  i generally start, when i'm lost, by removing all width attributes and going from there.  dunno if you've tried that already.

Comment: I tried that with no success.  The only thing that has worked has been to make my .page width very large, but then my login button is way to the right off of the screen on every page, and the only page I really need the width on is the index.

I've edited my question to include the .css code.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue with an ASP.Net MVC app I'm developing that I want to be usable on an iPad (e.g. Safari). An HTML table's width is controlled by it's content, in other words, the columns that make it up, and they will not become narrower than the least wide text in it that can be broken, in other words: not more narrow than any word using standard word breaks.

CSS3 supports a new word-break property, including a property value of break-all:
Lines may break between any two grapheme clusters within words. Hyphenation is not applied. This option is used mostly in a context where the text is predominantly using CJK characters with few non-CJK excerpts and it is desired that the text be better distributed on each line.

So, adding 'word-break: break-all' to the 'table td' section solved this for me in browsers that support it, most importantly Safari on the iPad. It now looks like this:
table td

```
{
  padding: 5px;   
  border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```